# Performing jumma prayer in the battle field

Tags: salat, hadith, battles

Is it permissible to offer jummah prayer behind a qualified imam in the battlefield when the regular salat is offered in individualistic approach?

Comment: Jummuah prayer isn't obligatory unless you hear the adhan.

Quran 62:9

Comment: @Sayyid, why? Anyone from group can not call the adhan?

Comment: Perhaps it could be nice offering such practice (in case there is enough time doing it).

Comment: Part of answer is posed here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12869/islamic-laws-for-salat-while-in-battlefield-or-at-war